# How to build a strong (rare earth) permanent magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, ferromagnetism

I think first of all one should use a material with a strong magnetic anisotropy.$^1$ Then all spins only really point either up or down.

But one also needs to achieve strong remanence. That is after magnetizing all atomic spins in the up direction, we need to keep them in this direction and prevent a flip in the down direction even after removing the external field. How do we achieve this strong remanence? How can we prevent the spins to flip after removal of the field?

---

$^1$Best suited is probably a magnetocrystalline anisotropy. With their only partially filled f-orbitals rare earth metals e.g. are very rotationally antisymmetric. So there will probably some angular orbital momentum orientation which leads to a less strong overlap of the wave functions of the nearest neighbour atoms and thus is energetically favourable. Thus creating such an anisotropy.

Comment: Do you know how the theory of ferromagnetism usually works? In particular, do you know why the spins in a generic ferromagnet below the Curie temperature don't randomize once the field is removed?

Comment: @probably_someone Yes I do know that, due to the Heisenberg term $\delta H=-J\sum S_i S_j$ which arises from exchange interaction. Or at least I know the simplification of this, the Ising model. Can one understand it based on this? It doesnt not need to be too technical or rigorous.

Comment: Is the idea to have such a strong $J$ that it is even significant at $T\approx300 K$?

Comment: Well, in that case you've partially answered your question, "How do we achieve this strong remanence?" You need an exchange interaction strong enough that the Curie temperature is above room temperature. This is probably necessary but not sufficient, though - lots of materials with Curie temperatures above room temperature nevertheless have low remanence (e.g. permalloy).

Comment: @probably_someone I didn't know that materials had such high curie temperatures! thank you. I looked at a table and I am shocked that Iron and Cobalt have Curie Temperatures on the order of $1000 K$! I always thought this was way lower ($1 K$ or so) because we don't measure any spontaneous magnetization in normal chunks of iron. But when thinking about this it makes sense.. That we don't have net magnetization is an effect of the macroscopic Weiss domains, microscopically the iron is in an ordered state even at room temperature.

Comment: We do measure spontaneous magnetization in natural materials, though. Magnetite, for example, is a form of iron oxide that is naturally ferrimagnetic, and magnetism was originally discovered because people noticed that pieces of iron were attracted to magnetite.

Comment: @probably_someone Natural permanent magnets are not spontaneous but were made by the magnetic field of a lightning strike.

Comment: @Pieter After having been struck by lighting they did not go back to the $M=0$ state due to naturally occuring impurities (pinning)?

Comment: If you need such a magnet, I wold suggest you do a web search and find a company that knows how to make them.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum Indeed, in some minerals the coercivity is large. Close to a lightning strike, the magnetic field is large enough to magnetize them. That is why such permanent magnets are always found near the surface and not in mines.

Comment: @R.W.Bird I only need to understand them a bit, as this was a question for the solid state first cycle exam. Producing them will be hard, I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to keep domain walls from moving, they need to be pinned. This depends strongly on inhomogeneities in the material on a mesoscopic length scale (metallurgy).

Strong uniaxial magnetoanisotropy makes for narrow domain wall, which are more easily pinned. So that depends on crystal structure with low symmetry and magnetic atoms with large spin-orbit coupling (this is why rare-earth elements are included).

It is complicated.

Comment: Okay, but I begin to understand on a simplified level. The bigger the anisotropy $\delta H=-\kappa|S_z|^2$ in comparison to the Heisenberg term $\delta H=-J\sum S_iS_j$, the smaller the domain wall as every bit of domain wall has a high energy cost $\kappa$ associated with it. And the smaller the domain wall the easier to pin the domain walls. Can I say in a very simplified picture that the domain walls stick to impurities during the shrinking process of the domains when lowering the magnetic field? And define pinning as the act of bringing such impurities in the material?

Comment: Yes, except for the last sentence, one does not say it like that. Heat treatment for example may produce precipitates where domain wall are likely to get pined. It is a bit of an art to get a large value of the coercivity.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I think the physics of this domain wall pinning is very complex. But this will be enough for my exam I hope, thank you for your help. I learned a lot!